# showing top 2 values (or bottom 2) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

The current code I have finds the average and shows all 4. I am trying to trim it down to only show the information for the top **2 highest average**. The current code I have is below.

```
SELECT BRANCHSUBURB, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS 
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) ASC;
```

I would like to only show the bottom 2 values(which will be the highest)
Or if it will be easier, show the top 2 values(and sort by descending order)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT BRANCHSUBURB, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
      FROM BRANCH NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS 
      GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
      ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) ASC
     ) x
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can use ANSI standard functionality, so a subquery is not necessary:

```
SELECT BRANCHSUBURB, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS 
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) ASC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, The first solution you posted works perfectly :).